# bash truncate string Works on commandline but not in script

Tags: string, bash, console, trim

I am trying to cut off all occurrences of a character from the end of a string.

The test script I came up with is:

```
#!/bin/bash
Input="/tmp/blah/bloh/////////////"

Desired="/tmp/blah/bloh"

cut='/'

result=${Input%%+(${cut})}

echo "          Input: ${Input}"
echo "Expected result: ${Desired}"
echo "         Result: ${result}"
echo "---------------------------------------"
echo -n "        Outcome: "

[ "${Desired}" = "${result}" ] && echo "Success!" || echo "Fail!"
```

Running this script via bash /tmp/test.sh gives the following output:

```
          Input: /tmp/blah/bloh/////////////
Expected result: /tmp/blah/bloh
         Result: /tmp/blah/bloh/////////////
---------------------------------------
        Outcome: Fail!
```

However, if I copy and paste the entire thing in my console I get the expected result of /tmp/blah/blah

What is going on here?

Comment: Replace `#!/bin/bash` with `#!/bin/bash -i` ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+(${cut})` is an extended pattern, which `bash` does not recognize by default. You need to enable the `extglob` option first.

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ Input="/tmp/blah/bloh/////////////"
$ cut='/'
$ echo "${Input%%+(${cut})}"
/tmp/blah/bloh
```

You probably have `extglob` enabled in your interactive shell via your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` configuration file, but neither file is used for the non-interactive shell started by your script.